# Redirect, and keep query string [javascript]

Tags: string

I want to create a re-direct in JavaScript for the following functionality;

Once someone has landed on a webpage, there will be a JavaScript that will temporarily direct them onto a webpage (they will be on this webpage for a very short time, so the page can capture the cookie/IDs), and then redirected again to a different webpage;

So for example:

I land on www.bbc.co.uk?ID=1234, I then get directed to another webpage, which is carrying my query string, www.google.com?ID=1234, then immediately I get directed to the final webpage, www.facebook.com.

And there maybe 1, or more query strings that will need to be carried over from bbc onto google. No query strings on the third and final webpage.

I want to ask, if this is possible? It must be in JavaScript, I know to direct somebody in JS it's simply;

So far, my workings as:

> window.location.href =

I can get the query strings by:

> var vars = [], hash;
>       var q = document.URL.split('?')[1];
>       if(q != undefined){
>           q = q.split('&');
>           for(var i = 0; i < q.length; i++){
>               hash = q[i].split('=');
>               vars.push(hash[1]);
>               vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
>           } }

Help/Advise will be very appreciated!

Answer (score -2):

You can get the query string of the window with the following call: window.location.search

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp

Comment: I'll take a turn highlighting a stackoverflow classic... w3schools is not the best source: http://www.w3fools.com/